# Simplifying and cancelling with algebraic fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I looked in my school's math textbook that I'm going to learn algebraic fractions very soon. I've read over the chapter but still don't really quite get the topic.

I know how to do really easy algebraic fractions like $\dfrac{1}{2a}+\dfrac{2}{3a}$ but I don't know how to simplify and cancel out algebraic fractions.

This is the type of algebraic fractions I do not get:

> $$\begin{array}{cc}\dfrac{12x-4}{36x+4}&\dfrac{x^2+x-12}{x^2+7x-30}\\\dfrac{5x+15}{7x+21}&\dfrac{x^2+2x-35}{x^2-3x-10}\\\dfrac{6x^2+12x}{3x^2+6x}&\dfrac{x^2+8x+15}{x^2-25}\\\dfrac{10x^2+20x}{5x^2+10x}&\dfrac{x^2+6x-16}{x^2-4}\\\dfrac{x^2+9x+20}{x+4}&\dfrac{3x^2+x-4}{5x^2-7x+2}\\\dfrac{x^2-5x-14}{x-7}&\dfrac{3x^2-4x-15}{5x^2-9x-18}\end{array}$$

Comment: Would you post some of the fractions you are having some trouble with?

Comment: Oh, hey, its you!  :)  anyways... yes, please expand on what you are confused on.

Comment: Are you trying to do what I did below backwards?

Comment: Oh, big fractions?  (use `\cfrac`): $$\cfrac{\cfrac1{2a}}{\cfrac1{a+1}}?$$

Comment: It's unclear of what you're asking. I am flagging this question until you revise on what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

So you want to simplify the fractions you posted? I'm not sure which one you have difficult with so just gave you a hit: try to express the functions in

$\mathrm{A(Bx\pm C)} or \mathrm{(Ax\pm B)(Cx\pm D)}$

For example the first one you have
$\frac{12x-4}{36x+4}$, you can write them in the form like $\frac{4(3x-1)}{4(9x+1)}$ then you can cancel the 4.

For the second one you have $\frac{x^2+x-12}{x^2+7x-30}$ you can write them in the form of $\frac{(x+4)(x-3)}{(x+10)(x-3)}$, Then you can cancel the (x-3) if (x-3) not equal to 0.

Comment: Thanks! All I was saying that how can I simplify if I encounter a problem like that. Those were just online problems.

Comment: @galaxymcpvp Then that could be different based on what the problem you are dealing with. But if you want to simplify a polynomial over a polynomial then I think trying to factorize them is always a good option.

Answer (score 0):

How do you add a half and a third?

$$\begin{align}\frac12+\frac23&=\frac36+\frac46\tag{Make a common denominator}\\&=\frac{3+4}6\\&=\frac76\end{align}$$

Same thing happens with algebraic fractions:

$$\begin{align}\frac1{2a}+\frac2{3a}&=\frac3{6a}+\frac4{6a}\tag{Make a common denominator}\\&=\frac{3+4}{6a}\\&=\frac7{6a}\end{align}$$

Comment: I think the OP was clear on this type of fraction, but not on 'others' hence my comment above.

Comment: @Bacon Good point